# POST Data From IOS App TO PHP Web Service (Hosting GODADDY)

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, iphone

I have to POST data from IOS App to PHP Based Webservice, Posting is working but table filled with NULL values. I have given code IOS and PHP
**Am Using GODADDY HOSTing**

IOS

```
- (IBAction)saveweb:(id)sender {

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&mail=%@",_name.text,_mail.text];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLen = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",[post length]]; 

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/test/t1.php"]];

NSMutableURLRequest * rq  = [ NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 

[rq setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[rq setValue:postLen forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];    

[rq setValue:@"application/x-www-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[rq setHTTPBody:postData];   

NSURLConnection *con  = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:rq delegate:self];

NSLog(@"%@",postLen);
 if(con){
     NSLog(@"connected");
 }
NSLog(@"%@",con);}
```

PHP Code

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "admin";
$password = "admin";
$dbname = "user";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 if (!$conn) {
     die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }else{
 }
$sql = "insert into user(name,mail) values ('$name','$mail')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

PHP My Admin ScreenShot

[image]

Comment: Your query is open for sql injections.

Comment: https://github.com/rintoandrews90/InsertingToWebService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Fixed It, Thanks For All

PHP

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "admin";
$password = "admin";
$dbname = "user";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 if (!$conn) {
     die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }else{
 }
$name = $_POST['name'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
echo "Name : ". $name;
echo "Mail : ". $mail;
$sql = "insert into user(name,mail) values ('$name','$mail')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>
```

IOS

```
NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&mail=%@",_name.text,_mail.text];

NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString UTF8String] length: [myRequestString length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.example.com/test/t1.php"]];

[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];

[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

[request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil];

NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[returnData bytes] length:[returnData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",response);
```

Answer (score 1):

May be your query is wrong.

```
$sql = "insert into user(name,mail) values ('".$name."','".$mail."')";
```

Try below code instead of "**NSURLConnection *con  = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:rq delegate:self];**"

```
NSError *err = nil;
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData   *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:rq returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: Its Not Working , I Did it. Thanks

Comment: Is there any changes to be maid in godaddy hosting ?

Comment: posting is working but NULL values are inserted int table

Comment: can u plz chek screenshot attached ?

Comment: php is working perfect i tested using postman plugin - chrome

Comment: first 3 rows are created using postman plugin in chrome, after all from ios

Comment: Thanks , U helped Me To Find the answer

Answer (score 0):

1. Try out your query on phpmyadmin to check its correct or not .

   2. Try [SVHttp](https://github.com/TransitApp/SVHTTPRequest) Or [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for making GET or POST request easily that will handle all in one method .

For Example : USing SVHttp : You need to drag and Drop the SVHttp folder in your project . Check copy if needed and then make request to your URL like this :

```
SVHTTPClient *request = [SVHTTPClient sharedClient];
NSMutableDictionary *params=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[params setObject:@"abc" forKey:@"uname"];
[request setBasicAuthWithUsername:admin password:admin];
[request setSendParametersAsJSON:NO];

[request POST:@"http://your server URL"
   parameters:params
   completion:^(id response, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"response : %@",response);
}];
```

:)

Comment: Sure .. Let me know If you are facing any issue . and please upvote if you find this solution correct !

Comment: thanks i will try this , but it supports only json based inputs,

Comment: You can change as you needed , It makes simple API requests . I edited Answer Please check .